# Curly brackets in HTML

Tags: html

I stumbled upon this code:

```
<a href="#" class="text1"{text2}>...</a>
```

What does the `{text2}` do? Later on, this HTML is replaced with:

```
<a href="#" class="text1" {text2} style>...</a>
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the `text2` value with jQuery?

Comment: It gives a parsing error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases that code is input in, so scripts can actually easily identify a the line.  Or in some cases can be an indicator for a database to retrieve and store data once it has been pulled.

Or it could be invalid markup, doubtful if the person knows what they are doing.

But without any other information or variables it is hard to say.  But the most common is access for scripts within Php, Javascript, and even C#.  Cause they can parse the HTML document and manipulate it.  *If those braces are used, and it is incorrectly it will cause a parse error.*

Hopefully that sort of clarifies it.

---

**Update:**

Yes, jQuery can find it.  It is a form of Javascript.  You could implement something such as:

```
$(function() {
    var foundString = $('*:contains("{text1}")');
});
```

There is a vast amount of data that addresses this for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but I actually meant: is there a way, given a `$(this)`, to find the text in the brackets? So given the `<a>`, get a function to return the text `text2`? Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to place a variable in the page, then use jQuery to return the value in that variable to the page itself from the script?

Comment: Yes, that would be an application of it. Basically, I'm working with someone else's code and I'd like to get the information stored there, because it's somehow used as an `identifier'.

Comment: The short answer, yes I could.  The correct answer, not here.  It turns into a discussion and doesn't physically adhere to your question anymore.  You'd have to ask a specific question so it adheres to SE Terms.

Comment: Okay, I did that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15279830/1544337 Thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 4):

It does nothing in HTML. It's actually invalid markup. Looks like maybe you have a template system that finds and replaces that before it gets rendered to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I know that in jinja2, a python templating system, brackets contain commands to the template engine, either as:

```
Hello, {{varName}}
```

or:

```
<ol>
{%for l in varList%}
<li>{{l}}</li>
{%endfor%}
</ol>
```

That's in jinja, but jinja has similar syntax to django templates, and many other template engines probably copy django's syntax also.

Answer (score 2):

its used in [angular js](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp) and are called expressions `{{expression}}`

> AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. It can be added to an HTML page with a  tag.
>
> AngularJS extends HTML attributes with **Directives,** and binds data to HTML with **Expressions**.