# Get invalid HTML code in curly brackets with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some (invalid) HTML code *which I cannot change*:

```
<a href="#" id="text1"{some-data}>...</a>
<a href="#" id="text2"{some-other-data}>...</a>
```

With jQuery, I select one of the two anchors:

```
function someFunction(id) {
  $('text'+id)...;
}
```

Now, I'd like to get the text inside the curly brackets. So, for `id=1` this would mean `some-data`, for `id=2` this would be `some-other-data`.

How can I do this?

To make it easy: there will be only one curly bracked thing in one element.

Comment: Maybe asking how to fix the *invalid HTML* would be wiser?

Comment: Why don't you use an actual data attribute? Who knows what kind of weird side-effects raw text like that could have inside the element tag.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I would to that, but it's not my code and I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: IE reorganises the arguments within a tag. I believe you'll never reconstruct the data on that browser.

Comment: use regex on $('#[ID]').html()

Comment: @JanDvorak that's interesting, because _why the hell is it there_ then? (Rhetorical question)

Comment: @ParvSharma can you show me a basic example in an answer?

Comment: @CamilStaps what's there? The definition order of tag attributes holds no semantic value. `<div id="foo" class="bar">` is the same element as `<div class="bar" id="foo">`. IE doesn't remember which attribute came first in HTML.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, you said, it wouldn't be possible to reconstruct the data in IE. This application is browser-compatible, so _if_ the data in the brackets is used, it should be possible to reconstruct it. But if it isn't, like you said, then what would be the use of adding it to the HTML?

Comment: @CamilStaps invalid HTML is invalid. You can pray there are no spaces, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak oops, there indeed weren't. Sorry!

Comment: @CamilStaps in that case I believe the solutions posted by others will work.

Comment: Looks like a template to me. is the code located in a `<script type="template">` element (or similar)?

Comment: @zzzzBov no, it's just like normal HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically you want to get the 'outer' html and then search for whats in between the curly braces.

The first part of that has been solved here

[Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

So using the outerHTML plugin from that question

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<div>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

function someFunction(id) {
  return $('#text'+id).outerHTML().match(/{(.*)}/)[1];
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works because the value may not contain spaces. If it did, it would produce incorrect results, even in Chrome.

Comment: `<p>` cannot contain block-level elements IIRC; certainly not other `<p>`s. I recommend switching to a `<div>`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, good call.  I updated the answer to include a `<div>` instead of a `<p>`